# How can I deal with pointer assignment compile error (error: no viable overloaded "=") in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I'm a rookie, and when I was doing [Leetcode 21. Merge Two Sorted Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/)
I submitted this code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* list1, ListNode* list2) {
        p1 = list1;
        p2 = list2;
        while (p1 && p2) {
            if (p1->val <= p2->val) {
                p->next = p1;
                p1 = p1->next;
            } else if (p2->val <= p1->val) {
                p->next = p2;
                p2 = p2->next;
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
        if (!p1) {
            p->next = p2;
        }
        if (!p2) {
            p->next = p1;
        }
        return head->next;
    }
private:
    ListNode* p1, p2;
    ListNode* head = new ListNode(-101);
    ListNode* p = head;
};
```

but got a compile error:

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
        p2 = list2;
        ~~ ^ ~~~~~
```

also:

```
this->p1 = list1;
this->p2 = list2;
```

got the same error message.
But after I modified the error code (inside the `mergeTwoLists()` function) to:

```
ListNode* p1 = list1;
ListNode* p2 = list2;
```

The code can pass the testcases and no errors occured.

Q1 : I want to know why it is necessary to implement `operator "="` for such a pointer assignment (`p1` or `p2` are `ListNode*` type and `list1` and `list2` are also `ListNode*` type) issue.

Q2: Also can someone show me how to implement the `operator "="` according to the error message(which can passed the testcases)?

Q3: Or if there is another solution (other than my above modification and implement the `operator=`)to this compile error message (which can passed the testcases).

Thanks!

Comment: The asterisk is not attached to the type, but to the variable name. `ListNode* p1, p2` is equivalent to `ListNode* p1; ListNode p2;`, not `ListNode *p1; ListNode *p2;`

Comment: @AlexSveshnikov ok, now I know the error, I have seen it before, but I just cannot quickly figured it out after the compile error message throwing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very common error

```
ListNode* p1, p2;
```

should be

```
ListNode *p1, *p2;
```

You need to use `*` on both variables to make both of them pointers.

Since this is confusing, and easily forgotten, most style guides recommend splitting the declaration.

```
ListNode* p1;
ListNode* p2;
```

Comment: Sorry asking for such a dumb question :( , now I know where the error occurs.

Comment: No problem, it's a common gotcha, and every now and then it still gets me.